# Bionic Ear help

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, microphone

I'm trying to build a "bionic ear" (or spy listening device). I want it so I can more easily locate kittens or cats stuck in garages, etc. (I work in cat rescue).

I tried to build [The Big Ear](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/the_big_ear) from Nuts & Volts online and I bought nearly everything new from DigiKey and afaik, I built the circuit correctly. However, all I'm getting from it is very light tapping noises when I tap the side of the mic (not when I tap the top) and all else I hear is a bunch of noise. The volume control works.

Can you take a look at the circuit and maybe help me troubleshoot where the problem might be at? Or let me know if the circuit design itself has issues?

I would greatly appreciate it. I'm a novice but am keen to learn. Everything is currently set up on a breadboard (see pic).

Update:
After going over the circuit a bunch of times, I did find a number of mistakes. I didn't have the other side of the pot going to ground, the zener(D3) was in backwards (ty GodJihyo), I failed to connect pins C7 and pin 8 of IC2 to J2 and didn't include the required 1k resistor for the mic I'm using (ty Hearth).

New results:
Well, now all I'm getting is a repeating "thut-thut-thut-thut-thut..." about the frequency of a heavy military helicopter. Volume control is not working. Mic is not working.

Although I know it probably does nobody all that much good to see my breadboard, I'm updating the pictures anyways just in case. Also including specs on the mic I'm using (Archer/RadioShack) 270-090).

Circuit:

[image: The Big Ear circuit]

Breadboard:
Layout and relative positioning mirrors circuit design.

I can take closer zoomed in images of any area of the breadboard if anyone wants to see the connections.

Left side (IC1):
[image: IC1]

Right side (IC2):
[image: IC2]

Mic:
[image: Archer 270-090 mic]

Comment: What kind of microphone are you using? Different types require different amplifier circuitry.

Comment: Archer/RadioShack 270-090 (see my update with spec image). I added the 1k resistor that it needs, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to tell from the photo but I suspect that the zener diode D3 may be connected the wrong way around. It should have a marking (usually a black band) on the cathode side. That side should go to the resistors but it looks like it goes to ground. If it’s in the correct way you should measure close to the rated zener voltage across it, if it’s backwards you’ll measure something like 0.6 V. This supplies voltage to the microphone element so if it’s wrong you will get little to no signal.

Comment: That's impressive debugging from a photo.

Comment: @Neil_UK Now to wait and see if I was right :D

Comment: you were totally right about the zener. I've got it the correct way round now but the circuit is still not working (see my update).

Answer (score 1):

> now all I'm getting is a repeating "thut-thut-thut-thut-thut..." about the frequency of a heavy military helicopter.

That is called motorboating.  It is a low frequency feedback problem almost always caused by the audio power amplifier.  Often it is caused by having the input signal ground share a trace or wire with the output signal return from the speaker.

ALL audio power amplifier chips, including little ones like the LM386, and notorious for requiring extra power supply decoupling.  The only decoupling capacitor on the schematic is C10.  Not only is it inadequate, but its physical location actually is as important as its value.

1. Have two decoupling capacitors for *each* IC:  1 - 0.1 uF ceramic, and 1 - electrolytic cap between 10 uF and 100 uF.  If you have another 100 uF (C6), use that with IC2.
2. These should be placed as close as possible to the two power pins on the IC, with the shortest possible leads.  Place the ceramic cap closest, and the electrolytic right against it.  Since you are doing this on a protoboard, have the caps straddle the ICs with the ceramic's pins in the closest holes to the ICs and the electrolytics in the next closest holes.
3. From each IC have a short jumper directly from the negative power pin (pin 4 for both ICs) to the GND bus.  Don't daisy-chain it to other grounded component pins.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed easy to read answer! A couple ?s:  1. I should replace C10 with something larger? Move somewhere else? 2. I should add a 0.1uF ceramic in series between IC2 and C6? Then add similar two caps to IC1? I'm also a bit confused when you say "straddle" the ICs. Sorry for my newbness ;!.